# How to change value of item in stl list?

Tags: c++, stl

I have a question about changing or replacing elements in a list. I have a class:

```
class Node{ 
public:
   elType type; // enum
   string name;

    Node(elType type, string name);
   ~Node();

    void printNodeInfo();
}
```

and a list:

```
    std::list <Node * > someList;
```

Now how can i replace a value (for eaxmple change type) in such element.
I've tried this:

```
        std::list<Node * >::iterator it = someList.end();
        it--;

        while(openName.compare((*it)->name) != 0)
            it--;

        (*it)->type = otherType;
```

But it does not seem to work, the type stays the same. I'd be grateful for any help.

---

EDIT:
I updated the list so now I have:

```
std::list <Node> someList;
```

and changed the replacing to:

```
it->type = otherType;
```

I also tried:

```
std::list<Node >::iterator it2 = someList.erase(it);
Node temp(otherType, openName);
someList.insert(it2, temp);
```

after this for both cases a simple method for printing :

```
it2->printNodeInfo();
```

outputs nothing.

Comment: Your search is recreating `std::find_if`, and you can also use plain equality: `str == otherStr`

Comment: your while loop should check with begin() so that it doesnt continue out of bounds if it doesnt find 'name'

Comment: Make sure *it is not nullptr. Print out type after setting. Use a debugger.

Comment: It always find name because it is inserted there. Why I start from the back of the list is because there may be more than one occurrence and i want just the last one.

Comment: And if you want to search backwards use `auto iter = someList.rbegin();` and then you can search using ++. Even better combine this with @chris 's suggestions and use `auto iter = std::find_if(someList.rbegin(), someList.rend(), [](Node *toTest){return toTest->name == openName;});`

Comment: Why are you storing `Node *`s instead of `Node`s in the `std::list`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is your problem exactly, but here is your solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class Node{
public:
   int type; // enum
   string name;

    Node(int type, string name) : type(type), name(name) {}
   ~Node(){}

    void printNodeInfo() const {cout << type << ", " << name << endl;}
};

void replace(list<Node> &l, const string &nameSearch, int typeReplace) {
    for (auto it = l.rbegin(); it != l.rend(); it++) {
        if (it->name == nameSearch) {
            it->type = typeReplace;

            /* To stop searching */
            return;
        }
    }
    /* Nothing replaced, error message? */
}

int main() {
    list<Node> l;

    l.push_back(Node(0, "World"));
    l.push_back(Node(1,"Hello"));
    l.push_back(Node(2,"World"));

    replace(l, "World", 42);

    for (const auto &el: l) {
        el.printNodeInfo();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As I see it, you would replace the first Node with type '2' and set `type = 42;`. The OP wants to find the last matching `name` and set `type`, so it's not exactly the solution.

Comment: Not quite. Now you search by `type` and replace `name` - OP want the opposite. ;-) Also, you still find the first match, not the last. See OP's comments to question above.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you use `Node *` instead of `Node`. Consider using `list<Node>` instead of `list<Node *>` unless you can give a reason why not.

I assume a `list<Node>` for now.

To find an element use [find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) from the STL. You can use it like that `find(someList.begin(), someList.end(), value)`; value would be of type `elType` in your case.

You also have to provide a comparison operator that compares a node's name to a give name.

Not having enough information I made a simplified example of yours. Maybe that gets you corrected/closer to what you want to achieve.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

enum elType { red, green, blue };

using namespace std;

class Node{ 
public:
   elType type; // enum
   string name;

    Node(elType type, string name);
};

Node::Node(elType type, string name) { 
    this->type = type; 
    this->name = name;
};

// ensure that name can be found using find of STL
bool operator==(Node &n, string name) {
    return n.name == name;
}

int main() {

    // Create nodes
    Node n1(elType::red, "Node 1");
    Node n2(elType::green, "Node 2");
    Node n3(elType::blue, "Node 3");

    // Output node names and types
    cout << n1.name << " : " << n1.type << endl;
    cout << n2.name << " : " << n2.type << endl;
    cout << n3.name << " : " << n3.type << endl;

    // Create list of nodes
    list<Node> someList{ n1, n2, n3 };

    // find node with name "Node 3"
    auto it = find(someList.begin(), someList.end(), "Node 3");

    // if a node was found change its type to red
    if ( it != someList.end() ) {
        it->type = elType::red;
    }

    // output nodes in list
    cout << endl;
    for ( auto node: someList ) {
        cout << node.name << " : " << node.type << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can, as mentioned by other users, also use the reverse iterator.
In that case simple replace `begin()` and `end()` by `rbegin()` and `rend()` like so:

```
    // find node with type "blue" and change type to "red"
    auto it = find(someList.begin(), someList.end(), "Node 3");

    // if a node was found change its type
    if ( it != someList.end() ) {
        it->type = elType::red;
    }
```

Comment: Ok, I changed the list to list<Node> but it seems I still can't replace the values in object.

Comment: Please update your question with your changes. You should show what you tried.

Comment: OP tries to search by `name` not `type`, so your `operator==()` needs to be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: if the item is not present `std::find` will return `someList.end()` and it'll crash. Also `rbegin()` and `rend()` to search from the back as in the OP.

Comment: Yes, you are probably right. But it was more about giving the OP an idea or a feeling how he/she could go about it. That's all.